# non static setGravity cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to android development, but know a little Java.  I am having problems knowing where to place Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0) in my code.

Here's the code:

```
package ca.ignitestudio.geoquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);



    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can you mark `setGravity` as `static` e.g. `public static setGravity(..)`?

Comment: No I can't because it gives me more errors if I do.

Comment: How come `makeText` works then?

Comment: The problem is the .show() at the end.  It's a shortcut for when you don't need to call the instance of the class.  So, I had to do it the long way and use a variable for the instance instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to call setGravity this way:

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
```

Comment: Beat me by about 40 seconds. Shouldn't have wasted time formatting my code... :)

Comment: Thank you kindly.  That worked.  I had the right idea but it was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`setGravity` is not a static method, so you should call `setGravity` on your toast instance, i.e.

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0); 
t.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `setGravity()` on an instance, not on the class. Change

```
Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
```

to

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
toast.show();
```